# Date.new returns undefined method `div' for "11":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the error

> undefined method `div' for "11":String"

pointing to the `@startdate` line when I submit the form.  I don't understand what's going on at all.  If I do the steps in the rails console it works fine.

In my controller I have:

```
@startday = params["startday_#{i}".to_sym]
@startmonth = params["startmonth_#{i}".to_sym]
@startyear = params["startyear_#{i}".to_sym].to_s
@endday = params["endday_#{i}".to_sym]
@endmonth = params["endmonth_#{i}".to_sym]
@endyear = params["endyear_#{i}".to_sym].to_s
@startdate = params["startdate_#{i}".to_sym]
@price = params["price_#{i}".to_sym]
@currency = params[:currency]
@startdate = Date.new(@startyear, @startmonth, @startday)
@enddate = Date.new(@endyear, @endmonth, @endday)
```

The hash I am sending is:

```
{
  "startmonth_1"=>"2",
  "startday_1"=>"11",
  "startyear_1"=>"12",
  "endmonth_1"=>"2",
  "endday_1"=>"13",
  "endyear_1"=>"12",
  "price_1"=>"12",
}
```

If I do a

```
@startee = @startyear.to_s + '-' + @startmonth.to_s + '-' + @startday
return render :text => @startee
```

I get:

> 12-2-11

So I don't see the problem.  Everything seems to be working ok.

Comment: Unlike JavaScript, PHP, Perl and other languages with very loose typing, strings and numbers in Ruby are entirely different things. You need to convert accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're passing strings to `Date.new` when you need to pass integers:

```
@startday = params[:"startday_#{i}"]
@startmonth = params[:"startmonth_#{i}"]
@startyear = params[:"startyear_#{i}"].to_s
@endday = params[:"endday_#{i}"]
@endmonth = params[:"endmonth_#{i}"]
@endyear = params[:"endyear_#{i}"].to_s
@startdate = params[:"startdate_#{i}"]
@price = params[:"price_#{i}"]
@currency = params[:currency]

@startdate = Date.new(@startyear.to_i, @startmonth.to_i, @startday.to_i)
@enddate = Date.new(@endyear.to_i, @endmonth.to_i, @endday.to_i)
```

Further, if you don't need to use these variables in your view, there's no need to make them instance variables and you should make them local variables instead (i.e. drop the leading `@` in the name).

Comment: Those rather arbitrary `.to_s` calls are redundant if you later convert `to_i`.

Comment: @tadman Yes but I don't know if the OP depends on it outside of this code snippet for some reason so I opted not to alter them. Granted, they should always already be a string anyway.

Comment: Or `@startdate = Date.new *[@startyear, @startmonth, @startday].map(&:to_i)`

Comment: Awesome thanks.  The to_s where in there because I was building a string before and trying it a different way.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if you were capturing the parameters using a more orderly definition: `Date.new(*%w[ year month day ].collect { |k| params["start#{k}_#{i}"].to_i })`